# Loop - invoke 'stride' with CGFloat

Tags: arrays, loops, swift3, cgfloat

**My code:**

```
for i:CGFloat in 0.stride(through: 100, by: spaceBetweenMarkers)
```

**Error:**

> Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(through: CGFloat, by: CGFloat)'

How can I use for loop by using a `CGFloat` value? I am using Swift 3. I want to iterate from 0 to 100 and pass a `CGFloat` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

let cf0 = CGFloat(0.0)
for cf in stride(from: cf0, through: 2.0, by: 1.0) {
    print(cf, type(of: cf))
}
```

prints

```
0.0 CGFloat
1.0 CGFloat
2.0 CGFloat
```